# How to identify type of draggable item?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to drop an object dragged from a third party application to a wxpython application. I know the content of the object is basically a string but I dont know how to specify the type so that the drop is accepted by the wxpython application.

By "type", I refer to this documentation: http://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop

> If you are not using a built-in data type, choose a *type specifier* (a unique string used to identify the datatype). **Only targets whose type specifiers include one of the current data source specifiers will be eligible for drops**.

An example of type specifier is 'text/x-moz-message' for thuderbird data.

How to find the type specifier of an unknown object or how to force the wxpython application to accept any drop?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your best bet is to use `wx.PyDropTarget` and `wx.DataObjectComposite`, from which you can call `.GetReceivedFormat().GetType()`.

There's an example app on the wxPython wiki:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop#wxDataObjectComposite

Comment: Thanks for your reply The problem is that the app wont allow a drop unless you "register" the datatype using the add function. It looks like I need to know the type beforehand.